# Magento 2 Zend XmlRpc Client not found

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, xmlrpc

I am trying to implement Magento 2 Odoo connector by using Zend XmlRpc Client.

```
$httpClient = new \Zend\Http\Client();
$oxClient = new \Zend\XmlRpc\Client('http://192.168.2.114:8069/',$httpClient);
```

But it throwing an error like `Class 'Zend\XmlRpc\Client' not found`

Does magento 2 supports Zend XmlRpc Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zend 1 standard: `new \Zend_Http_Client();` and `new \Zend_XmlRpc_Client()`

See more examples about `Zend_Http_Client` under: `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Service`

Comment: Thanx for your quick repy.I can load http client class but not xmlrpc class for magento 2.
new Zend_XmlRpc_Client() it throws same error.

Comment: Should take a look some samples: `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/OpenId/Consumer.php`. Search through your magento with the keyword `Zend_Http_Client()`. You can see more.

Comment: I am trying to call this function under a custom module in app/code folder.So can you explain how can i send xmlrpc request to odoo by using Zend_Http_Client() method?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Odoo. You should open new question. Additionally, you can see some example module: `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Service/Amazon.php`

Comment: Sorry @khoa ,it still throws error ` Uncaught Error: Class 'Module\Name\Odoo\Api\Def\Zend_Http_Client'` not found.

Comment: Hey! Seem that you try to call the class like `Module\Name\Odoo\Api\Def\Zend_Http_Client`? Additionally, should not create a class name like this.

Comment: No @khoa.Inside my module ..like this 
$httpClient = new Zend_Http_Client(); $oxClient = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://192.168.2.114:8069/',$httpClient);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56236/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-renjith).

Comment: The error is self explained. Seem that you tried to call a class doesn't exist. Make sure this class is available and the module of this class is enabled.